# post JSON array using curl

Tags: php, api, curl

Hi I'm having a problem with posting a JSON array with cURL to my API,

```
   JSONData='
        {

            "customerCode": "DUMMY",
            "fromLocation": {
             "suburbName": "MELBOURNE",
             "postCode": "3000",
             "state": "VIC"
            },
            "toLocation": {
             "suburbName": "SYDNEY",
             "postCode": "2000",
             "state": "NSW"
            },
            "goods": [
             {
               "pieces": "2",
               "weight": "3",
               "width": "10",
               "height": "20",
               "depth": "12",
               "typeCode": "ENV"
             }
            ]
            } ';
```

and i am using this code to pass array but it does not work

```
$data_string = stripslashes($JSONData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)                                                                       
)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('JSONData'=>$data_string)

);
```

Please Help me to pass JSON array.

Comment: Instead of POSTFIELDS what we can we use to pass json array

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong. I think you just want to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string)`. FYI, rolling your own JSON is rarely a good idea. Construct an array in PHP then use `json_encode()` instead

Comment: If that doesn't work, I recommend using an HTTP library like [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Much easier than working with the cURL lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$username='xxx';
$password='xxx';
$url='http://apiurl';
$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => array('Content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($username.':'.$password)),
            'content' => $JSONData
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo 'response: '.$response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify the content type as `application/json`, you will have to `json_encode`  the *full* data. So try with,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('JSONData'=>$data_string));
```

As a side note, you can also replace `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "TRUE");`.